# Balls in the space of bounded operators on a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, hilbert-spaces

Suppose $\mathsf{H}$ is an infinite-dimensional (non-separable preferably) Hilbert space. Consider the space $L(\mathsf{H})$ of all bounded operators on it. Is there $0\neq W\in L(\mathsf{H})$ such that the set

$$\left\{ T\in L(\mathsf{H} )\colon \|W-T\| = \|W+T\| \right\}$$

contains an open ball? Is this set a linear subspace of $L(\mathsf{H})$?

Answer (score 1):

It has been asked and answered [at Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/77527/balls-in-spaces-of-operators).